# links not working in IE11 - javascript related issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on a site that functions normally in every web browser with the exception of IE11. The issue is that any images I have that link to another page are disabled (i.e. logo image, menu links).

I've narrowed the culprit down to a responsive menu javascript (jPushMenu) that uses jquery. I have a fiddle where I've stripped everything down:

https://jsfiddle.net/cy83v725/

And here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,IE=11,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/davincid.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick-1.5.7/slick/slick.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick-1.5.7/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
        <!--[if IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/davincid-ie7.css">
        <![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jPushMenu.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <title>DaVinci Digital | Innovative, Complete IT Solutions</title>
    </head>
    <body id="home">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!-- Responsive design starts here -->
     <!-- Left menu element-->
<nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left">
    <h3><a><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close Menu</a></h3>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="who-we-are.html">Who We are</a>
    <a href="what-we-do.html">What We Do</a>
    <a href="your-team.html">Your Team</a>
    <a href="our-clients.html">Our Clients</a>
    <a href="helpdesk.html">DaVinci Helpdesk</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</nav>
    <div id="button">
                <button class="btn toggle-menu menu-left push-body"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> MENU</button>
            </div>
            <div id="DDLogoRsp">
                        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/Davincid-logo.gif" class="logo" alt="DaVinci Digital" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pageTitleResponsive">
                </div>
                <div id="ContentArea">
                    <div class="indexRsp">
                    <div class="resp-slideshow"/>   

                    </div> 
                                <div class="tagline">
                <img class="resp" src="images/tag.gif" align="right" alt="Providing 100% referral based professional services since 1993"/>
            </div> 
                    </div>
                    </div>
        <!-- Responsive design ends here -->
        <div id="main">
            <div id="DDLogo">
                <div id="headWrapper"> 
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/Davincid-logo.gif" align="left" alt="DaVinci Digital" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                    <ul id="NavContainerAlt"> 
                        <li id="whoWeAre"><a href="who-we-are.html"></a></li>
                        <li id="whatWeDo"><a href="what-we-do.html"></a></li>
                        <li id="contact"><a href="contact.html"></a></li>
                        <br class="clear">
                    </ul>
                <div id="indexContentArea">
                    <div class="slideshow" align="center">  

                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="tagline">
                <img class="resp" src="images/tag.gif" align="right" alt="Providing 100% referral based professional services since 1994"/>
            </div> 
            <div class="DDrawing">
                <img src="images/davinci-drawing.jpg" alt="Davinci"/>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div id="Footer">
            <p class="Footer">©2016 DaVinci Digital  All Rights Reserved.</p>
            <p class="Footer">&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
    <!--load jQuery, required-->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <!--load jPushMenu, required-->
        <script src="js/jPushMenu.js"></script>

        <!--call jPushMenu, required-->
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.toggle-menu').jPushMenu();
        });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the jPushMenu javascript:

```
/*!
 * jPushMenu.js
 * 1.1.1
 * @author: takien
 * http://takien.com
 * Original version (pure JS) is created by Mary Lou http://tympanus.net/
 */

(function($) {
    "use strict";
    $.fn.jPushMenu = function(customOptions) {
        var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.jPushMenu.defaultOptions, customOptions);

        $('body').addClass(o.pushBodyClass);

        // Add class to toggler
        $(this).addClass('jPushMenuBtn');

        $(this).click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();

            var target     = '',
            push_direction = '';

            // Determine menu and push direction
            if ($(this).is('.' + o.showLeftClass)) {
                target         = '.cbp-spmenu-left';
                push_direction = 'toright';
            }
            else if ($(this).is('.' + o.showRightClass)) {
                target         = '.cbp-spmenu-right';
                push_direction = 'toleft';
            }
            else if ($(this).is('.' + o.showTopClass)) {
                target = '.cbp-spmenu-top';
            }
            else if ($(this).is('.' + o.showBottomClass)) {
                target = '.cbp-spmenu-bottom';
            }

            if (target === '') {
                return;
            }

            $(this).toggleClass(o.activeClass);
            $(target).toggleClass(o.menuOpenClass);

            if ($(this).is('.' + o.pushBodyClass) && push_direction !== '') {
                $('body').toggleClass(o.pushBodyClass + '-' + push_direction);
            }

            // Disable all other buttons
            $('.jPushMenuBtn').not($(this)).toggleClass('disabled');

            return;
        });

        var jPushMenu = {
            close: function (o) {
                $('.jPushMenuBtn,body,.cbp-spmenu')
                    .removeClass('disabled ' + o.activeClass + ' ' + o.menuOpenClass + ' ' + o.pushBodyClass + '-toleft ' + o.pushBodyClass + '-toright');
            }
        };

        // Close menu on clicking outside menu
        if (o.closeOnClickOutside) {
             $(document).click(function() {
                jPushMenu.close(o);
             });
         }

        // Close menu on clicking menu link
        if (o.closeOnClickLink) {
            $('.cbp-spmenu a').on('click',function() {
                jPushMenu.close(o);
            });
        }
    };

   /*
    * In case you want to customize class name,
    * do not directly edit here, use function parameter when call jPushMenu.
    */
    $.fn.jPushMenu.defaultOptions = {
        pushBodyClass      : 'push-body',
        showLeftClass      : 'menu-left',
        showRightClass     : 'menu-right',
        showTopClass       : 'menu-top',
        showBottomClass    : 'menu-bottom',
        activeClass        : 'menu-active',
        menuOpenClass      : 'menu-open',
        closeOnClickOutside: true,
        closeOnClickLink   : true
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Here is what's confusing to me:

1. When I open the Developer Tools console, the links work.
2. When I resize the page to make it smaller, the links work.
3. When I go to jPushMenu's demo page in IE11, the links work ( http://takien.github.io/jPushMenu/ )
4. When I look at the site on a mobile device using IE11, the links work (namely, the logo image that links to the home page).

I'm a novice with javascript, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: Not that I can see, but I'm not 100% sure that I'm using the console correctly.

Comment: I've tried to open jPushMenu.js from IE11, and got the error 'jquery' is undefined.
I've tried to open jquery from IE11, and get 'window is undefined.'

When I go to the console tab (for the page), it says 0 errors and 0 warnings.

Comment: Please post your code here, not as an external link.

Comment: code is posted, as well as a jsfiddle. Please let me know if it should be formatted differently or if I've done something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your HTML including a self closed div that can confuse things.  I believe the immediate issue can be resolved however by taking the `z-index: -5` off of your html and body elements.

Comment: Oh.My.God. THANK YOU!!! That did it. I had a thought that it could have nothing to do with the javascript itself. I'll verify that getting rid of that doesn't cause any formatting issues, and if it does, I'll find another workaround. THANK YOU again. I've been at this for days, literally.
I've given you a +1, but I don't have the clout for it to show up on your reputation. :)

Comment: @CharityBabcockJedeikinb - try accepting the answer when you can ;-)  (from an onlooker)

Comment: Thanks @Traktor53 - done! I didn't see that before as an option. My first time posting here, probably not my last. :)